# Using xamarin android designer in visual studio doesn't change layout

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm using the android designer in visual studio 2010, and I can put things on the layout without a problem. when i click to change the view from '4in WVGA (Nexus S)' to anything else, the background 'bounding box' changes size, but the content does not resize.

This happens even if I just create a brand new layout and don't put anything onto it.

Also, when I try to apply different themes, nothing changes. Anything I'm doing wrong, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that this is a known bug. MonoDevelop works fine. I assume they're working on it.